# iOS App free to paid

Tags: ios, app-store

I have published a app in iOS app store. This is currently free to download. I have around 1K active daily users. I am planning to convert this to paid app ($0.99) in my next update/upgrade.

My question is - If i change this to paid app in my next upgrade/update, will existing downloads/users be affected. Will they be able to download the update or will existing users also have to pay for the update.

Thanks,
SP

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business concern related to the App Store, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Answer (score 3):

> If i change this to paid app in my next upgrade/update, will existing downloads/users be affected.

You're just changing the price from $0.00 to $0.99, so people who "bought" the app at its earlier price will continue to have it, and will continue to get updates, without paying again.

Comment: even if the person uninstalls and installs it again?

Comment: Yes, once you buy an app, it's in your list of purchased apps and you can install it on all your iOS devices. Price changes only affect people who haven't bought the app yet.

Answer (score 1):

People that already have your free app will have it and all future updates for free for ever, whether or not you add a cost to it.